# How to accelerate pandas?

Tags: performance, python-2.7, parallel-processing, pandas

I have a number-crunching program that goes through a csv file (2500 rows x 180 columns) and for each row performs a bunch of computations. It summaries these computations after going past each row and then puts all of the summaries into a new dataframe. This takes very long, about 30 seconds or something. I am looking to build another program which will create about 20 of these new dataframe and I am afraid that it will take a very long time to complete the entire cycle.

Is it possible to do parallel processing in pandas? Is this the best way to accelerate?

Edit: The summaries for each row are dependent on the previous ~800 rows.

Comment: This is a bit broad this question, it depends on what you are doing. Are the summaries dependent on other rows? It sounds like it is not so it would be better to import the whole csv, assuming it can all fit in memory and perform the operation on the whole dataframe or panel

Comment: Yes, they are, thank you for clarifying.

Comment: It would be better to post your code that you think is slow, better yet try different strategies include the times and we can comment on a better approach. As the rows are dependant on previous rows then it makes sense to import the entire dataset into multiple dataframes or a panel and then summate over all the data. Depending on the operation performed it can be very fast

Answer (score 1):

you can use modin.pandas it's faster than pandas x4 approximately and it has the some functions.this package use parallel-processing.

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing your code, you have a few options.

1. Try your code in cython. http://cython.org/
2. Try running your code with pypy. http://pypy.org/
3. Run your code on a faster server (e.g. AWS).